# Can you control the order of passes while adding it to Apple Wallet?

Tags: ios, swift, passbook, wallet, passkit

I am using this API to add multiple grouped passes to Apple Wallet.
I realized that added passes in the wallet doesn't follow the order of array [PKPass] that I gave it to this API.

```
public func addPasses(passes: [PKPass], withCompletionHandler completion: ((PKPassLibraryAddPassesStatus) -> Void)?)
```

The interesting thing to note here is when I tap on `View All` before adding the passes it does show all the passes in order but after tapping on `Add All` and then launch the Wallet app to see the order od added pass it's not same anymore.

Any clue why this is happening and how to maintain an order?

Comment: Apple doesn't mention nothing about pass order on their documentation, so to be honest, I  don't think it's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no documentation or `PassKit` API which states in which order can passes appear in Wallet app.

It can only be done manually as stated [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204003).

> To reorder your passes, tap and hold a pass, then drag it to a new place. With iOS 7 or later, your change will update on all of your devices.